# jquery background-color animation not applying

Tags: jquery

I'm experiencing a strange issue..

`row.animate` doesn't do anything, but `row.css` does? Both methods are in the same scope like in this complete-handler function

```
function(){
    row.animate({
        background : 'red'
    }, {
        duration : 200
    });

    row.css({
        background : 'red'
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post ur row html tag

Comment: you should using jQuery UI to animate `background-color`, http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted that solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [.animate() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> **width**, **height**, or **left** can be animated but **background-color** cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color() plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) is used.

You could use **CSS3 animation** instead!

Here is the **Working Code Snippet**:

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-animation: changeColor 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: changeColor 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
  from {background: red;}
  to {background: yellow;}
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  from {background: red;}
  to {background: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Readup: [`animation` - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and [`@keyframes` - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Answer (score 2):

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the **[jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)** plugin is used.